# Error no shadowed variable - tslint error

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, tslint

Having tslint warnings (ES6) and still having some difficulty with its syntax. It show as following

> **error no-shadowed-variable: Shadowed name: 'i'**
> [image]

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.UploadedFilesArray.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.UploadedFilesArray[i] != undefined) {
        var tempx = this.state.UploadedFilesArray[i].toString().split('|');
        str.push(<li key={tempx[0]} onClick={this.onChangeDeleteDocument.bind(this)} data-id={tempx[1]}> Uploaded File : {tempx[0]} - <a className={styles.MyHeadingsAnchor}>Delete </a></li>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `no-shadowed-variable` rule's documentation here: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-shadowed-variable/

> When a variable in a local scope and a variable in the containing scope have the same name, shadowing occurs. Shadowing makes it impossible to access the variable in the containing scope and obscures to what value an identifier actually refers.

It'd be helpful to see the full file, but really what's happening is that you've declared some `i` variable in one block, then *within* that block, declared another `i` variable.